# How do I execute my loop at a relatively short time?

Tags: matlab, loops

It is taking like forever (over 6 hours) to execute a loop. The size of my variables are;

Z = 2041211 element

Distance = 2021x2021 double

```
for duidx = 1:Z
    Summation_Residual_Squared(duidx) = sum(Residual_Squared(Distance_Unique(duidx)==Distance));
    Semivariance(duidx) = Summation_Residual_Squared(duidx)/(2*sum(Distance(:)== Distance_Unique(duidx)));
end
```

Am I working with large files such that the execution time I'm obtaining is normal or is there something i'm missing.

Thanks. 
Darl.

Comment: What are the `Residual_Squared()` and `Distance_Unique()` functions? What is are the shapes at each point?

Comment: Have a look at the Vectorization page in matlab's documentation: http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/vectorization.html

Comment: Vectorization is definitely one approach to consider for improving your code's performance, as @Swier said. Here is a [full list](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/techniques-for-improving-performance.html#buwj1l5) of all of the recommended methods (vectorization is included) for improving your code's performance. Please take some time and make it more clear what each expression in your code refers to. For instance, is `Distance_Unique` a function or an array? Why do you convert your 2D `Distance` matrix into a 1D array by `Distance(:)` in the 2nd line of the loop?

Comment: Residual_Squared and Distance_Unique are arrays with size of 2021x2021 and 2041211x1 respectively. What I am doing in the 2nd line of the loop (Distance(:)== Distance_Unique(duidx)) is to count the number of times each element in Distance_Unique appears in Distance Matrix. I will look at the Vectorization. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## Explaining Long Execution Time

I wouldn't say that the cause of the long runtime you are experiencing is the size of the matrices you are operating on, per se. Rather, it is the excessive number of iterations performed within each line of code inside the `for` loop. In addition to the 2,041,211 iterations of the `for` loop, you are performing [image: 2021^2 = 4084441] iterations in the first line of code alone! Of course, larger data sets are always going to take a longer time to process... but rarely hours (unless you're parsing large chunks of unstructured text or large sets of MB-large poorly organized XML files).

## Diagnosing the Real Culprit

### Memory Efficiency

The easiest solution is to just figure out how much of your computer's RAM you are using currently. If Matlab doesn't have enough memory to work with, it will perform notably slower than usual - the people who maintain the Matlab documentation are well aware of [memory problems many Matlab users experience](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_prog/strategies-for-efficient-use-of-memory.html), too. Before running your code, maybe it would be beneficial to just run the `clear` command to make sure you don't have unused data lying around taking up precious space in memory.

### Use the Profiler Tool!

Everything above is just my best guess as to what is causing your system to run so slow. If you are interested in identifying for yourself the particular functions in your code that take the most time to execute, use the [`profile`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/profile.html) command built-in to Matlab. To start the profiler, just insert the line `profile on` at the first line of your code. To view the results of the profiler, just insert the line `profile viewer`. I illustrate this in the code snippet I provide below. This will open a separate figure that outlines how long each function in your code took to execute, and from this information you can find out what exactly it is that is taking so long.

I would suggest testing this with a much smaller sample size of your data. You could test it with just the first 100 values of your `Distance` and `Residual_Squared` arrays, just to see which functions take the most time executing without having to wait the whole 6 hours of execution time (even a Lord of the Rings marathon couldn't occupy you for too many of those runs).

## Improving the Performance of Your Code

I think that you can significantly reduce the number of computations you perform in this code in two simple steps. First, by only performing as many computations as you need to: `(Distance_Unique(duidx)==Distance)` from the 1st line of code in your `for` loop and `(Distance(:)== Distance_Unique(duidx)` from the 2nd line of code in your loop only need to be done once, if I am reading the purpose of those conditional statements correctly. Second, by just performing operations with built-in functions like `find` and `ismember`, that you are currently performing by brute-force with conditional statements.

For instance, it seems that the goal of the first line of code is to find all indices in `Distance` that are equal to a specific value `Distance_Unique`. Then, you sum together all the values at those indices in `Residual_Squared`. You could replace it with this, taking advantage of functions like [`find`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/find.html) and [`ismember`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/ismember.html) to do the same thing:

```
profile on

% Declare 'Distance', 'Unique_Distance', 'Residual Squared' matrices here

Z = length(Distance_Unique);
% Preallocate the arrays that store results to speed things up a little more
Summation_Residual_Squared = zeros(Z, 1);
Semivariance = zeros(Z, 1);

for idx = 1:Z
    % Your 1st line of code
    inds = find(ismember(Distance(:), Distance_Unique(idx))); % Find indices of all hits of current value of Distance_Unique in Distance matrix
    Residual_Squared_Array = Residual_Squared(:); 
    Summation_Residual_Squared(idx) = sum(Residual_Squared_Array(inds));

    % Your 2nd line of code
    num_hits = length(inds); % Number of times a given member of Distance_Unique array shows up in the Distance matrix
    Semivariance(idx) = Summation_Residual_Squared(idx) / (2 * num_hits); % You already know the total count of the given member of Distance_Unique because you can access the length of 'inds'
end

profile viewer
```

It has been my experience that Matlab's built-in functions are more efficient (and therefore perform their operations much faster) than any quick logic you can write out in conditional statements. Further, breaking your code into smaller steps of the whole makes it easier to see how you can use the data that you've already processed (as you see in the code snippet I provided above).

I hope that these suggestions help you out, happy coding!